# Send large string from Android to MVC

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc, string, asp.net-mvc-4, long-integer

I'm trying to send a very large string from android to my mvc application and back to android. Below is my codes for the MVC application.

```
[HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage RetrieveString(String longString)
    {
        var resp = new HttpResponseMessage()
        {
            Content = new StringContent("{\"ResultString\":\"" + longString + "\"}")
        };
        resp.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
        return resp;
    }
```

Here is the code for the android application

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        String JSONStr = null;

        try {
            final String URL = "http://172.27.179.197:7837/api/TestCon/RetrieveString?";

            Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(URL).buildUpon()
                    .appendQueryParameter("longString", params[0]).build();

            URL url = new URL(builtUri.toString());

            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("connection", "keep-alive");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
            urlConnection.connect();

            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            if (inputStream == null) {
                return null;
            }
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line + "\n");
            }

            if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                return null;
            }
            JSONStr = buffer.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error ", e);
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error closing stream", e);
                }
            }
        }
        return JSONStr;
    }
```

This codes work fine is I'm sending in short string. However, when the string get too long (hundreds or thousands of characters), the Android application throws a "java.io.FileNotFoundException: `http://172.27.179.197:7837/api/TestCon/RetrieveUserByEmail?inputEmail=<<Very Long String>>"` exception. Any advice on how to send this long string across to MVC? Thanks!

Comment: Why are you adding the string as a query parameter not a 'form post' paramter?

Comment: Simply send the files to the server.

Comment: Hi Vsevolod Goloviznin,

How do I send it as a "form post"?

Comment: Hi  jitain sharma,
How do I send the files over to the server? I tried using MultipartEntity but i have no idea how to receive the value from the server side.